# Convert complex roots into standard float form without affecting quality of result

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a transformed stress tensor, its principle values are coming in complex form:

```
#simple roots calculated by characteristic equation
def  princ_cherac(sten):
    sxx,syy,szz,sxy,syz,szx = sten
    H1 = (sxx+syy+szz)/3.
    H2 = (syz**2 + szx**2 + sxy**2  - syy*szz - szz*sxx - sxx-syy)/3.
    H3 = (  2*syz*szx*sxy  +  sxx*syy*szz   -  sxx*syz*syz  - syy*szx*szx - szz*sxy*sxy    )/2. 
    from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P 
    p = P([2*H3,3*H2,3*H1,-1])  
    S3,S2,S1 = p.roots()
```

but it produces complex roots. For my further calculations, the complex form cannot work. How can I convert from the complex form while not losing any information on the results, for example, `S3 =-32.894653311352783-28.288180652364915j`; how to change it so that the answer represents it but in normal float-like form?

Comment: Which language are you working with? Only tag the language you're using.

Comment: python and numpy function but i am flexible with other languages
but its more related to mathematics. then just one language.

Comment: Please don't spam with unrelated language tags, that will only get your question down-voted and/or close-voted. Edit your question to remove unrelated tags.

Comment: What should `-32.894653311352783-28.288180652364915j` convert to, exactly?

Answer (score 3):

There is a mistake in your implementation of `H2`.  You have the last term as `sxx-syy`, but that should be `sxx*syy`.

By the way, you'll likely get more accurate results by using [`numpy.linalg.eigvalsh`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigvalsh.html) to find the values.  For example, here's a full 3x3 tensor; `coeffs` are the values to be passed to `princ_cherac`:

```
In [200]: tensor = np.array([[2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2]])

In [201]: coeffs = tensor.ravel()[[0, 4, 8, 1, 5, 2]]

In [202]: tensor
Out[202]: 
array([[2, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 2]])

In [203]: coeffs
Out[203]: array([2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
```

Compute the values using `eigvalsh`.

```
In [204]: np.linalg.eigvalsh(tensor)
Out[204]: array([ 1.,  1.,  4.])
```

Compare that to the values produced by the corrected `princ_cherac`:

```
In [205]: princ_cherac(coeffs)
Out[205]: (0.9999999619754828, 1.0000000380245182, 4.0)
```

Comment: thanks budddy . u made my day :* THanks for your precious time